# How to fix interface syntax error using as type?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface:

```
export interface DocumentBlock {
    children: DocumentBlock[] | DocumentField[];
}
```

When I try to set type `DocumentField` in foreach:

```
  this.documentBlock.children.forEach((element: DocumentField) => {});
```

I got this error:

> Type '(element: DocumentField) => void' is not assignable to type

When I add: element: `DocumentField | DocumentBlock` IU dont have `type` property in `DocumentField` when I try to get it:

```
element.type
```

I have tried this:

```
 this.documentBlock.children.forEach((element: DocumentField | DocumentBlock) => {
            if (element.type == 0) {
                (element as DocumentField).visible = true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Your solution works though, no? The Problem is that at some point you have to tell typescript which interface you're using if they have different properties, because `element` can't be both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done is totally correct and the only way to solve your problem. basically you need a way to [assert the type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) you're passing to your function in order to make the TS compiler understand which one of two possible types that you may pass, you're actually passing.